# How to setup CentOS port forwarding on a VPS?

Tags: centos, udp, command-line-interface, vps, portforwarding

I bought a VPS for my game since I was developing and hosting it on my own network. I would simple do port forwarding between my router and my machine, making the config on the router's page. Now, I don't know how to do the same thing on the VPS (SSH). I read something about `iptables` but Idk if it is what I'm searching for. I just want to open an UDP port. There was Apache running fine and I stopped it. What commands should I use?

Comment: Can you clarify whether this is CentOS 6 or 7?  I believe 6 comes with iptables already installed, but 7 comes with firewalld.  Which do you have?  If you're not sure, you can run "cat /etc/redhat-release" and just post the output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem. I just shouldn't do any port forwarding, and bind the socket on the public address.